# How to restart node.js server gracefully?

Tags: node.js, express, webserver

How to correctly close all connections before restarting/shutting down the web server?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty nice npm module which I use to do some cleanups and so on... before the node.js process exists due to any reason (may be due to kill command from outside the process).

https://github.com/sindresorhus/exit-hook

To do the actual cleanup it depends on what you have running.
For example if its expressjs do server.close(); and so on....

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows, so in my cmd, I used to use netstat -ano and findstr command to find a node.js process and then taskkill /pid 1234 /F   ( 1234 is an example of pid)

However, it was so much work. Now, I use an easier way.

> taskkill /F /IM node.exe

This command will close all the node.js processes in one command.